# Standard wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery') doesn't load the script

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, codex

I develop a plugin and I want use jquery-ui-datepicker. And now I have huge problem. If I use construction like this:

```
function FQ_init_method() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'Free_Quotationadmin1-script', plugins_url('js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js', __FILE__) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'Free_Quotationadmin2-script', plugins_url('js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js', __FILE__) ); 
wp_register_style( 'Free_Quotationadmin-style', plugins_url('css/menu.css', __FILE__) );          
wp_register_style( 'Free_Quotation-style', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__) );          
wp_register_style( 'Free_Quotationadmin2-style', plugins_url('css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css', __FILE__) );    
}      

add_action('admin_init', 'FQ_init_method');
```

FireBug detect the jQuery and everything work. But admins on WordPress repository doesn't want accept my plugin if I use my own jQuery. They oblige me to use incorporated to WP version of jQuery. But if I use this code:

```
function FQ_init_method() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker');
wp_register_style( 'Free_Quotationadmin-style', plugins_url('css/menu.css', __FILE__) );          
wp_register_style( 'Free_Quotation-style', plugins_url('css/style.css', __FILE__) );                     
}      

add_action('admin_init', 'FQ_init_method');
```

FireBug doesn't detect any jQuery from my plugin... Why??? I don't have any idea...

--------EDIT--------------------------------

Sorry - this is not a problem. Now everything is OK but in FireBug i doesn't see information that I use jQuery. My mistake was in different place - ID of  data was different than should be, and own script (2.0.2) accept it. Now I correct it and everything work OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses jQuery [no conflict](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/), so it sits under the jQuery() namespace rather than the $() namespace. Could this be your issue?

Comment: But what does't mean? wp_enqueue_script should cause that I see jQuery in Firebug. Do I think correctly?

Comment: Exactly - Firebug see it in different way.